# Why is the recommended release of my module not proposed in Drupal updates?

Tags: 7, community-official-site

For my contributed module I've previously published several releases without any issue.

Most recent releases were successively `7.x-2.0rc2` then `7.x-2.0` and `7.x-2.1`.

As of `7.x-2.1` the following happens:

- for all Drupal sites having this module installed with an older release, the `admin/reports/updates` list doesn't mention the newest release (even after refreshing):

  - for a site currently in `7.x-2.0rc2` it proposes `7x-2.0`
  - for a site currently in `7.x-2.0` it tells it's up to date
- (may be not related but) simultaneously I noticed that the [git repository summary](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/multilang?h=7.x-2.x) doesn't show the labels for the tags corresponding to the 2 new releases, in its **Age** list

However at the same time:

- the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/multilang) shows the right last release in **Recommended releases** (and downloading it gives the right content too)
- the [git repository summary](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/multilang?h=7.x-2.x) shows the involved releases in its **Tag** list

BTW I noticed that some other older releases are also shown in **Tag** list while missing in **Age** list, so the git behaviour might not be relevant for this issue

Anynay keep wondering why the recommended release of my module is not proposed in Drupal updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately after posting my question, I'd pushed a new `7.x-2.2` release, and it didn't change anything: all involved sites keeped reporting `7.x-2.0` as the most recent release.

But today I noticed that it suddenly changed (without any intervention in `git` nor in my module's page): now the sites correctly report `7.x-2.2` as the most recent release.

So I tend to think that the response to my question is merely: there is some *variable* latency in the way Drupal.org makes the information available for the `admin/reports/updates/check` page underlying mechanism to work.

Moreover it worth mention that also the `git` **Age** list now shows all release tags, while some of them were previously missing.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed/enabled your 7.x-2.1 version of your module in a multilanguage D7 site (3 languages, 'en' is the default), in which I have never installed any earlier version of your module.

After doing so, I received a (red) Drupal error message (actually 2 identical ones) like so:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant _MULBASE_PATH - assumed '_MULBASE_PATH' in _multilang_install() (line 22 of .../sites/all/modules/multilang/multilang.data.inc).

And I also get an informational (green) message like so:

> NOTE: in order to use the advanced features available with CKEditor, you must install the Widget plugin.

The 'advanced features' in it is a hyperlink, pointing to `.../en/_MULBASE_PATH/en/admin/help/multilang#ckeditor`. Obviously following that link returns a page not found (because of the _MULBASE_PATH in it.

And within `admin/reports/updates` there is now (also) the yellow update message shown, from 7.x-2.1 to 7.x-2.0 (similar to your update messages).

Within `admin/reports/dblog`, there is now also a message like so:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in multilang_exit() (line 240 of .../sites/all/modules/multilang/multilang.module).

So could it be that it is somehow related to that **_MULBASE_PATH**, which I assume is a variable that has not receive an appropriate value yet?

Haven't done any other debugging or research so far, but I wouldn't be surprised if that could be what is causing your issue ...

PS: in the meantime I have discovered that, in the site where I did my experiment earlier today, my "module list" (at 'admin/modules') isn't working anymore (I'm using 'module filter' module also). When I visit that link, not even 1 module is shown anymore. Not sure yet if it is a memory issue (pretty sure it is not), because I added 1 more module. But since the only thing I did in this site today is my experiment with that 2.1-version of your module, I suspect that to be the culprit ... I can't even simply disable the module again by using the 'admin/modules' link (no modules are shown to enable/disable). So I'm planning to go edit the system table via PhpMyAdmin soon. I'll update my answer after I have more details on that.

Comment: Oops! What you pointed is a regression bug. I'd not detected it by myself because it ONLY happens at install time or when reading inline help, and I missed testing that again (shame :-). Besides that, nobody else opened an issue to report it, so thanks a lot for having alerted me about it. But I tend to think it's not the cause of my issue: first because this bug already existed in several earlier releases, and also because I can't figure out how the git<-->drupal.org mechanism might be aware of something which only regards the content of the release, no? Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I'm sorry if I were the cause of your problem! I agree it could be related with the presence of my module, since it happened to me months ago. I never could understand what had happened (happened only on one site, while other ones worked fine with the same release), but got rid out of it merely suppressing the whole `multilang` folder (there is no database nor variables involved with this module). So you may consider using the same simple method. Also I just published 7.x-2.2 which fixes the bug you pointed.

Comment: Oops (again!). Didn't pay attention to your 2nd comment, because I was immediately focused on the 3rd one. Yes, indeed, I agree that your answer is useful, so I just upvoted your answer, gladly. Please let me know if and how you could get rid of the "modules blank page".

Comment: FYI, several points: 1: I use to be closely concerned about any problem a user may experience related with my work. It's why I quickly began examining the successive issues you pointed out, so forgetting upvote BTW. 2: I only just noticed that your answer also stated a third problemn (the PHP warning). 3: for all that, may I propose you create an issue  (or may be several ones), where we can exchange more comfortably than in those comments? TIA.

Comment: "merci" for upvote! No problem about the various items you mentioned in your recent comments. I'm also a module maintainer (and know how it is like), check my profile for a 1st impression about "my" modules. Yes I'll create appropriate issue(s) on D.O for your module (soon). Right now I'm working on (temporary) "disable" of your 2.1 module in a Drupal-compliant way (without deleting the entire module dir). So give me some time to get back to you on this ... ça va?

Comment: "Ca va" :-) I just got the "Please avoid extended discussions in comments" message, so I'll say nothing else for now. But sure I were very interested to exchange with you about some points, notably the "modules blank page", that I suspect to be a Drupal issue.

Comment: Voilà, I recovered from the issue I encountered via the 7.x-2.1 version of the module. Refer to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161920/how-to-disable-a-troublesome-module-in-d7-that-causes-admin-modules-to-not-list/161921#161921 (and the answer I added) for more details. Later on (tomorrow or so), I'll create an appropriate issue in your issue queue on D.O. For now "I call it a week", au revoir!