# How to disable a troublesome module that causes admin/modules to not list all modules?

Tags: 7, installation

I ran into an unexpected situation after installing the 7.x-2.1 of the [Multilang - Embed multiple translations inside a unique node or block](https://www.drupal.org/project/multilang) module. I was actually experimenting with that module to better understand the question about [Why is the recommended release of my module not proposed in Drupal updates?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/161866/why-is-the-recommended-release-of-my-module-not-proposed-in-drupal-updates)

After I finished experimenting with that (version of that) module, I wanted to disable it again, via the typical `admin/modules` link. The link still worked (so no WSOD situation like you may get if you run into memory problems), but not even 1 module (enabled or disabled) was shown in my module list. So no way to "disable" that Multilang module from there.

**How can I disable this module without using the `admin/modules` link** (since there it doesn't show up)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I was lucky enough to have [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) available. So by simply using `drush dis multilang`, the module got disabled. And Eureca ... the link at `admin/modules` started to work again.
2. Even though I have not had to use another approach, this would have been my plan-b: disable the Multilang module manually in the database, via an SQL command like so:

   `UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='multilang';`

   or as a variation, using PhpMyAdmin (if that's available).
3. If for whatever reason plan-b would not have worked either, you could consider deleting the entire module folder (for module [Multilang](https://www.drupal.org/project/multilang)) in the modules directory where that module got installed. That would, pretty sure, have "killed" the trouble module also. Though it would have left the module's row in the `system` table in some bad shape (to be repaired afterwards, probably with something like the "[Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild)" module.

   However, as pointed out by [Molot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/16495/mo%C5%82ot) also (merci! aka thanks!), deleting files is problematic. Because it prevents you from ever running uninstall on a module. And [Registry Rebuild](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) will probably not fix that. So think twice before using this plan-c ...

Comment: Deleting files is problematic, because it prevents you from ever running uninstall on module. Registry rebuild will not fix that, as far as I know. so generally 3 shouldn't be suggested without strong warning, and claim that another module may repair things is bold one.

Comment: No problem. I only pointed that out because I screwed one of my sites that way. Nothing production, of course. For 2nd option - if one have [BaM](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) installed, he can save SQL command to file, and then use "restore" option. It will upload and execute file, any SQL file.

Answer (score 1):

When I run into a similar problem ([Devel Themer](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is such a case) I just delete the bothersome module folder and run **update.php**. Then I re-upload the module folder where it was before and it shows as deactivated in the module list. You can then uninstall it from the data base if you're not going to use it.

Comment: Hm, interesting alternative, especially if you don't have Drush available (or not familiar with using it). Thanks for sharing it!